# gulp is not creating destination folder for compiled file in eclipse IDE

Tags: gulp

I'm importing gulp task runner for my local projects. My problem is gulp is not creating destination folder for all the compiled files in eclipse IDE and I'm also refreshing my projects but not visible anything.

However, when I'm running those task in cmd then its showing running all tasks. Please help me to understand this.

```
>gulp.task('scripts', function(){
    gulp.src('javascript/src/*.js')
    .pipe(uglify()).
    pipe(gulp.dest('javascript/build/js'));
});
```

Comment: have you checked the physical path whether destination folders are created ?

Comment: thank you for answering. yes. it was able  to reslove it!